# Are the terms consensus mechanism and consensus algorithm the same?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I have seen that the terms `consensus mechanism` and `consensus algorithm` are used interchangeably sometimes. Are they really the same or there is a subtlety to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of abstraction. In general a mechanism is on a bit higher level of abstraction than an algorithm. It's something like "we have a mechanism to reach consensus - that mechanism is an algorithm".

So there isn't really any difference as such.